# Is there a difference between Simultaneous multithreading scheduling different processes and different threads in a process?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture

I am investigating the technology of `Simultaneous multithreading`. But I found that SMT technology was proposed long ago. Until 2008, after Intel introduced the Nehalem microarchitecture, most Intel CPUs supported Simultaneous multithreading technology. But before this, there were a lot of controversies about SMT, thinking that SMT may reduce performance better than the competition between threads for functional devices. Have these problems been overcome?
Is there a difference between Simultaneous multithreading scheduling different processes and different threads in a process?